# Is there any markup technique in FXML similar to data templates in XAML?

Tags: javafx-2, fxml

For example specifying UI for items in a ListView - declaratively.

The [XAML way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the items titled **fx:value**, **fx:factory**, and **Builders** under the [Instance Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#instance_declaration_elements) section in the [Introduction to FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) doc. There's also an example in the official [FXML tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm#JFXMG169).

Generally, the [main documentation page](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/) is a good starting point.

Comment: How is this an answer to the OP question?